# Contraction of the determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, determinant, tensors, exterior-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, we consider an orthonormal basis $e_0,\dots,e_n$ and $\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_n$ its dual basis. Then, the determinant is $\alpha_0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_n$. I am seeking a contracted formula for
$$
\sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_{n}} |\sigma|\det(e_0,v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(n)})
$$
In terms of differential forms, it is given by
$$
\sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_{n}} |\sigma|\alpha_{\sigma(1)} \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_{\sigma(n)}(v_1,\dots,v_n)
$$
Does anyone know a way to simplify this? $\Sigma_n$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Exterior_algebra

Comment: And what is $\alpha_0\wedge\alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_n(e_0,v_1,\dots,v_n) = \alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_n(v_1,\dots,v_n)$?

Comment: Sorry, I cant see the point of both of you